# How does the Facebook chat load new messages without you refreshing the page?

Tags: php, sql, chat

I'm trying to push my skills with PHP and SQL that I've recently learnt at college; I'm making a website that I can chat with some friends on. I know how i'll do everything ( log on, save messages & display messages ) but I'm unsure of how to make the messages constantly load instead of having to reload the page like on Facebook.

If I was to use this: while($sqlRow = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlResult)){

Would that keep loading messages as they're added to a table for holding messages?

Comment: you should look into web sockets. [This tutorial shows how to build a chat app with javascript, PHP and web sockets.](http://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

Comment: I think they do that with web sockets : http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sockets.php

Comment: I would imagine it's something that's achieved with WebSockets. I've used this previously; https://faye.jcoglan.com/ to do pub/sub messaging with NodeJS. It has websockets and fallback to older methods (ajax, etc) if the client doesn't support.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to implement this is to use web sockets: think of a web socket as a two-way communication channel that is always open between your client and your server. Even though your client is done loading the page, your server can still send messages to it through this open channel, at any time.

I have never used web sockets with PHP (only with javascript and node.js), so I can't really help you with how to actually implement this system. However I found this article that may help you: http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html

Let me know if that helps.